# How do I generate a confidence region for a set of sample from a bivariate posterior?

Tags: confidence-interval, python, sampling, bivariate, credible-interval

I have a set of samples generated from a posterior function as shown below:
[image: Posterior Samples]

I want to generate a bivariate High Posterior Density (HPD) credible region for the samples as in the below example ($\alpha=0.43$ and $0.1$ credible regions, green and blue respectively)?

[image]

I'm aware of how to do this in the univariate case but I can't find a lot of information on doing this in the bivariate case. Is there existing software to do this in python or an algorithm for doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one answered, the python package corner.py (https://corner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) provides a helpful interface for plotting HPD regions. The documentation is good and the code simple and clean.